# How can I check if a type is mpl::apply-able?

Tags: c++, boost-mpl

If I have a type, `T`, that looks like `Foo<mpl::_1>`, I can do `mpl::apply<T, int>::type` to get `Foo<int>`.

But if `T` is a complete type like, say, `Foo<int>`, then `mpl::apply<T, int>::type` will not compile.

I want to write a metafunction that will apply a type if possible, otherwise return the type. So something like:

```
template <typename Partial, typename T>
struct maybe_apply
: eval_if_c<??????,
    mpl::apply<Partial, T>,
    mpl::identity<Partial>>
{ };
```

What can I put in the ???s so that this does what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm far from an expert on MPL, so I can't promise that this is the best way to solve this (or even if it is correct, it seems to work at least).

According to the documentation, the first parameter/argument to `mpl::apply` needs to be a Lambda Expression, and that can be either a Metafunction Class or a Placeholder Expression. A quick google search led me to [this post](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/mpl-is-lambda-expression-bug-td4642509.html). According to that post, `mpl::is_lambda_expression` allows you to determine if a type is a Placeholder Expression. In Boost.TTI (that is in boost since version 1.54) you can find a metafunction that does exactly what you want. This metafunction is `boost::tti::detail::is_lambda_expression` and can be found in `boost/tti/detail/dlambda.hpp`. In the example below I have used the exact same macro that TTI uses to find if a type is a Metafunction Class.

[Running on Coliru.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5b28fdcaa8f11a93)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

#include <boost/utility.hpp>

#include <boost/mpl/apply.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/eval_if.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/identity.hpp>

#include <boost/mpl/plus.hpp>

namespace mpl=boost::mpl;


/* //This is another way to do it
template <typename T, typename Enable=void>
struct is_apply_able : mpl::false_
{};

template <typename T>
struct is_apply_able<T,typename boost::enable_if<mpl::is_lambda_expression<T> >::type> : mpl::true_
{};
BOOST_MPL_HAS_XXX_TEMPLATE_NAMED_DEF(is_metafunction_class, apply, false)
template <typename T>
struct is_apply_able<T,typename boost::enable_if<is_metafunction_class<T> >::type> : mpl::true_
{};*/


BOOST_MPL_HAS_XXX_TEMPLATE_NAMED_DEF(is_metafunction_class, apply, false)

template <typename T>
struct is_apply_able : mpl::or_<is_metafunction_class<T>,mpl::is_lambda_expression<T> >
{};

struct plus_two
{
    template <typename Number>
    struct apply
    {
        typedef typename mpl::plus<Number,mpl::int_<2> >::type type;
    };
};

template <typename T>
struct Foo
{};

template <typename Partial, typename T>
struct maybe_apply
: mpl::eval_if<is_apply_able<Partial>,
    mpl::apply<Partial, T>,
    mpl::identity<Partial> > 
{ };

int main()
{
    std::cout << typeid(maybe_apply<Foo<mpl::_1>,int>::type).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << typeid(maybe_apply<plus_two,mpl::int_<1> >::type).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << typeid(maybe_apply<Foo<float>,int>::type).name() << std::endl;
}
```